# How to animate particular table View cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

I have a table view that has 4 cells. And I want to hide first two cell for few second  And i am doing this -:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if historyArray.count > 0 {
        cell.alpha = 0
        if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 1,
            delay: 0.05 * Double(indexPath.row),
            animations: {
                cell.alpha = 1
        })
    }
    }
```

but this code has not worked for me. how to do this.

Comment: It is probably because of your logic in `if historyArray.count > 0` - `historyArray` is probably empty and so the block with the animation never gets executed.

Comment: How exactly does your snippet not work? What do you see on your screen instead of expected outcome?

Comment: If you want to animate cell better to use UICollectionView

Comment: use collectionview instead. plus will you tell me the count of historyArray?

Comment: history array count is 2

Answer (score 2):

can u pls try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.frame.width, y: 0)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
                cell.transform = .identity
            }
        }
    }
```